# Parts of Bash function don't execute on Linux

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script that will sit on my machine and listen for a file in a specific folder, then run a function to start an application. In the code below everything executes except the line "java -jar Minecraft.jar" and I am unsure why. I am not getting an error. I see the notification from the Notify statement. If anyone else could give me some direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

Launch_Minecraft () {
echo "Starting Minecraft..." 
cd .. &
cd Games &
cd Minecraft &
notify-send "Starting Minecraft"
java -jar Minecraft.jar & 
rm /home/MyFolder/Dropbox/Alexa/launchminecraft.txt &
cd /home/MyFolder/Desktop
}

for (( ; ; ))
do
   [ -f /home/MyFolder/Dropbox/Alexa/launchminecraft.txt ] && Launch_Minecraft|| echo "Listening... [ hit CTRL+C to stop]"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

[codeforester is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41472412/2877364) - `&` in bash doesn't mean "and do this next," but rather "move on to the next command without waiting."  Remove the trailing `&` from all lines except the `java` line and you should have more luck.

Other thoughts:

- `for ((;;))` can be replaced by `while :` or `while true`.
- use `[[ ]]` instead of `[ ]` for tests - bash has its own built-in tests.
- `x && y || z` can have unexpected behaviour if `y` fails.*  Instead, try:

  ```
  while true
  do
      echo "Listening... [ hit CTRL+C to stop]"
      [[ -f /home/MyFolder/Dropbox/Alexa/launchminecraft.txt ]] && Launch_Minecraft
      sleep 1   # or something to prevent this script from eating all your CPU cycles!
  done
  ```

`*` Note: In `x && y || z`, if `x` succeeds and `y` fails, `z` will be executed, which may not be what you think would happen.  E.g., `true && false || echo n` prints `n` even though `x` (`true`) succeeded.

Comment: I love the kindness of people like @chepner and cxw (can't quote more than one user).  I am new here and it is a pleasure to watch you guys contribute so much!  You inspire me.

Comment: @codeforester Thanks for the compliment!  In case you didn't already know (which you may well have) it won't let you @ cxw because replying to my answer automatically notifies me :) .  It took me a while to figure that one out when I started on SO!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you executing all the commands in the background with `&`?  That seems like the issue.

Comment: This may be my problem then. I was under the understanding that the "&" sign in bash would perform the operation and continue instead of waiting for the application to exit and then continue. In this example I would want the game to start and the script to continue instead of waiting on the game to exit and then continuing.

Comment: That is correct, but there is no point trying to change the working directory, then moving on without waiting for that change to take effect. (Also, a background executes in a separate process, so the change in working directory wouldn't apply to later commands anyway.)